# Get a delegate to set the size of a cell in a QTableView

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using a delegate to display a QPixmap from a QAbstractTableModel in a QTableView, like this:

```
void LabelDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
  QPixmap pixmap = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).value<QPixmap>();

  QRect rect = option.rect;
  rect.adjust(rect.width()/3, 0, -rect.width()/3, 0);
  painter->drawPixmap(rect, pixmap, pixmap.rect());
}
```

However, I want it to make sure that the cell is big enough to display the whole QPixmap. I tried using the sizeHint function:

```
QSize LabelDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
  std::cout << "sizeHint()" << std::endl;
  unsigned int sideLength = 300;
  return QSize(sideLength, sideLength);
}
```

but it doesn't seem to resize the cell. How would I force the cell size to match the QPixmap size?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the [resizeColumnsToContents()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#resizeColumnsToContents) and [resizeRowsToContents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#resizeRowsToContents) slots for QTableView.

Every time an item is added to your model, emit a signal and connect it with a slot that calls these two functions in order to update the geometry of your view.

Comment: Hm, I just tried that - the problem is if the columns/rows are bigger than the pixmap that gets drawn, they don't shrink to fit. Is there no way to force the size instead of relying on the resize*ToContents() functions?

Comment: You can use the [setColumnWidth](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtableview.html#setColumnWidth) function if you want a fixed column width. Similarly the setRowHeight. However I suggest the resizeToContents functions

Comment: Great. Thanks for the suggestion of using a signal inside the delegate!